# Scientific and numeric simulation in android which way? ndk?

Tags: java, c++, android, math

i want to write a scientific/numeric environment for android, i am collecting informations since i never developed anything for android or mobile.

I've recently heard about the native development kit, which should allow me to write C++ code for my android app, but i have some questions:

- Would it bring portability issues? due to compiling and code machine hell
- Are basic java mathematical functions and objects good (at least in android) or should i try for a custom implementation of common functions?
- Writing everything in java? would it bring me lot of performance loss if compared to ndk?

Comment: I have written numerical applications in Java.  I couldn't make any comparison with an equivalent C++ application, but I doubt it could have been any faster.

Comment: I would consider writing it all in Java first, then profile & optimise. If you find sections that are particularily slow, rewrite them with the NDK.

Comment: Get it right, If there are any performance issues find those and then optimize. For your first pass keep it simple -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> If you write native code, your applications are still packaged into an .apk file and **they still run inside of a virtual machine on the device.** The fundamental Android application model does not change.
>
> Using native code **does not result in an automatic performance increase, but always increases application complexity**.

So the good news is, **no portability issues**! The bad news is, it's not the same as compiling C++ code for the processor, so it might not give you the performance boost you're looking for. Moreover, it will definitely make your task as a developer much harder.

To reiterate the advice you received in the comments: **Get the functionality with pure Java first, then worry about optimizing later**.

Regarding "how good" the math objects are, the functions in [java.lang.Math](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html) are as good as you can do with `double`s.
It appears that the arbitrary-precision decimal and integer classes aren't in the android libraries, so you would have to write those yourself if you need them. The same goes for any higher-level objects (vectors (could use an `ArrayList` actually), matrices, graphs) Java does have a `Set` if you need that.